# SQL exception was unhandled (a network related ...)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am currently trying to connect to a database made in MS SQL Server and My program works on my system but when i want to access it through other computers in the same network  but i can not.
How could i edit my connection string? 
Which settings i should do on SQL server? 
Should i install SQL server management studio on other computers in the network? 
 Below is my code and an explanation of what is going wrong.
[connection string and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbACP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbACP.png)

Comment: If you paste the error message into the search box, you'll find hundreds of answers to that. I think the most useful could be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: i tried many solutions that they said...but they did not work.i am fraustrated

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Win+R to open Run command
2. Type **services.msc** and click OK
3. Check that **SQL Server(*Instance Name*)** must be in Running state.

Another thing you can try is

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Right click on Server in Object Explorer and select Properties
3. Go to Connections tab and **Allow remote connections to this server** checkbox must be checked

Comment: I check it.it is running.

Comment: I've updated one more thing. Could you please try that?

Comment: i did that . but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not configured **Firewall** on your main desktop(consider as server), So Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access. open port `1433` in windows firewall.
Also do the following steps in Server system:

- Make sure **tcp/ip** is enabled in Sql Server Network Configuration
- Set port :**1433**
- Restart sql server
- Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access like mentioned

**EDIT:** See how to [Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

Comment: I did all of them . But it does not work yet

Comment: @SedigheRahimi...So probably your problem is with your connection string. Can you show your connection string also?

Comment: i put the image at the end of question.plz click on the link

Comment: @SedigheRahimi...Well, what is the `ServerName` and `DBName`'s values?

Comment: they are two variables: public string ServerName = @"tcp:shiva-pc,49172"; public string DBName = "mydb";

Comment: I open the port 49172 on firewall and shiva-pc is computer name

Comment: @SedigheRahimi....You need to open the port `1433` in your firewall and also your server name seems to be incorrect change it to something like this: ServerName = `shiva-pc`.

Comment: ok i do that and i will be back.thank you

Comment: i could not set port to 1433,i dont know why...but it makes an error "windows could not start the sql server(mssqlserver2)on local computer.for more information , review the system event log....

Comment: @SedigheRahimi...See my updated answer to see how to Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access.